# Issue with the xsl code when weblogic upgraded from 10g to 12c

Tags: xml, xslt, upgrade, weblogic12c

My application which is using XML publisher and deployed in WEBlogic was working fine when it was in Weblogic 10g, after the upgrade it's giving issues with the XSL code elements
during the runtime in server.

```
XML-22132: (Error) QNAME validation error:  "invalid character  in name" .
```

this code was working fine before but after the weblogic upgrade it's giving issues in that particular piece of code.

```
<xsl:if test="$l-sell-price2 !=''"><xsl:element name="{$l-sell-price-tag2}"><xsl:value-of select="$l-sell-price2"/></xsl:element></xsl:if>
```

Could you please help in understanding the errror, I checked many forums but didn't get the above XML-22132 error

Comment: Show us a value of the variable or parameter `$l-sell-price-tag2` when you get the error.

Comment: @MartinHonnen  Hi it's reading from an XML field attribute.But in actual there is nothing set for that attribute. so it's null.

Comment: $l-sell-price-tag2 value is null, I put the <xsl:message> and checked the value it's null ...while for the other variable $l-sell-price2 the value is 0.0E0 and in server it shows 0